# Why DataContext for inner object is not updated?

Tags: wpf, datacontext

I have question about DataContext changes and I build example for understand this aspect.
I have MainUserControl on MainWindow. MainUserControl consists of number of User Controls.
One of such User Controls is SubUserControl1.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplicationUcBindingQuestion.MainWindow">
    <Grid>
        .....
      <uc:MainUserControl />
    </Grid>
</Window>

<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplicationUcBindingQuestion.MainUserControl">
<Grid>
.....
    <uc:SubUserControl1 x:Name="subUserControl1" />
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And in MainWindow I have object of class Info. Class Info consists of a few inner classes.
One of them is, lets say, SubInfo. Both Info and SubInfo classes inherits from INotifyPropertyChanged.

And this is the code of them:

```
public class Info : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private SubInfo m_subInfo = new SubInfo();

    public Info()
    {
    }

    public SubInfo SubInfo 
    {
        get
        {
            return m_subInfo;
        }
        set
        {
            m_subInfo = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SubInfo");
        }      
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    } 
}

public class SubInfo: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string m_subString = "subStr";

    public SubInfo()
    {
    }

    public string SubString 
    {
        get
        {
            return m_subString;
        }
        set
        {
            m_subString = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SubString");
        }      
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    } 
}
```

I want to set DataContext for MainUserControl to be object of class Info
and **for SubUserControl1 DataContext will be Info.SubInfo.**

The following code describes this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplicationUcBindingQuestion.SubUserControl1">
   <Grid>
      .....
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=SubString}"/> 
   </Grid>
</UserControl>

public MainUserControl()
{
        InitializeComponent();

        MainWindow mainWnd = (MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow;

        Info info = mainWnd.Info;
        this.DataContext = info;

        this.subUserControl1.DataContext = info.SubInfo;
}
```

When new subInfo arrived I update inner object subInfo inside info object:
(This is function of MainWindow)

```
private void OnUpdateData()
{
    SubInfo arrivedSubInfo = new SubInfo();
    arrivedSubInfo.SubString = "newString";

    m_info.SubInfo = arrivedSubInfo;
}
```

I want to see that DataContext for subUserControl1 is also changed.

But it doesn't happened and TextBox inside SubUserControl1 is not updated
and doesn't show "newString".

(Note: If  I write inside OnUpdateData() function the following:

```
m_info.SubInfo.SubString = arrivedSubInfo.SubString;
```

(copy field-field and not whole object) it works,
but I dont 'want copy 50 field...)

Where I'm wrong? 
Your help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is the following:

In your constructor, when you do that:

```
    this.DataContext = info;

    this.subUserControl1.DataContext = info.SubInfo;
```

You will set the DataContext ONLY once. Which means it will never change unless you write `subUserControl1.DataContext = someNewDataContext` somewhere.

What you can do to solve this :

**The "proper solution":**

Use a binding. In your XAML, just write:

```
<uc:SubUserControl1 x:Name="subUserControl1" DataContext="{Binding
SubInfo, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

This will work, assuming that your `SubInfo` property fires the `OnPropertyChanged` event when it is set.

**The "ugly solution":**

Explicitly set your `UserControl`'s `DataContext` in code-behind when you need it. Again, I wouldn't advise that and you are better off applying the first solution!

Comment: thanks for the quick answer. Your "proper solution" works. However, I have a question: why I need to update DataContext,

Comment: thanks for the quick answer. Your "proper solution" works. However, I have a question: why I need to update DataContext for subUserControl1 if I have PropertyChanged properties for both Info and SubInfo classes. I do not update DataContext for controls binded to Info object and they(controls) are updated with new values.

Comment: You don't have to "update it", but you actually have to specify that your binding should be updated every time you fire `PropertyChanged`. To do that, you need to specify it in the Binding expression with `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` . Default binding updates happen on `LostFocus`, and it is not always what you need